# How to execute goal after completion of Maven's package phase?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I need to copy packaged jar artifact from `${basedir}/target` into another subdirectory.

But when I try to utilize [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) I get broken jar with different size. I think it happens because `package` phase is not completely finished when [maven-resource-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) start coping.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-jar-after-package</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/dist</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                  <include>${artifactId}-${version}.jar</include>
                  <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `<filtering>true</filtering>`, otherwise Maven will go through the jar as if it was a text-file and will try to replace any matching `${*}`.